# How to hide the tooltip after certain time

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

How do i hide the tooltip after 4 seconds in react

The tooltip classes which i used works fine. The tooltip shows up when i hover on the label and tooltip disappears when i away from the label.I want to show the tooltip for 4sec on hover and hide after that .How do i do it in react?

```
     <Field
      name='termsAndConditions'
      label='Terms'
      component={Checkbox}
      hover={textOnTermsHover}//the text which is hovered
      time={timeAfterWhichItHide} // this is the amount of time 
                                 //the hover should display
    />




     export const Checkbox = (inputProps) => {
     const { input, label, hover, time } = inputProps
     const { name } = input

     return (
       <label className='checkbox-a'>
      <input {...input}  checked={checked} 
      type='checkbox' />
      <div className='checkbox-a__box' id={name} />

     <div>
     <p className='checkbox--links' tabindex='0' aria- 
     describedby='tooltip-cb class='tooltip'>
      <u>{label}</u>//label on whose hover the tooltip is 
     displayed
      <div role='tooltip' class='tooltip__content' id='tooltip- 
      cb-02'>{hover}</div> //the text which is hovered when on 
     label
    </p>
    </div>
    </label>
    )
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transition-delay` property, Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/tomerlevi/pen/mYBVjo?editors=1100).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add state to your component to keep track of when tooltip should be shown or hidden.
Here is your code with tooltip state tracking and delay handling.
Please note that code below requires React@16.8.1 and above as it uses the new hooks API.

```
//react@^16.8.1
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export const Checkbox = (inputProps) => {
  const { input, label, hover, time } = inputProps
  const { name } = input
  const timeout = useRef(null) // to store a handle to timeout so that it can be cleared
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false) // tooltip show/hide state
  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    // when mouse enters element
    if (!isShowing) {
      setIsShowing(true) // show tooltip
      timeout.current = setTimeout(() => setIsShowing(false), time) // schedule to hide tooltip
    }
  }
  const onMouseOut = () => {
     // when mouse leaves element
    if (isShowing) {
      setIsShowing(false) // hide tooltip
    }
    if (timeout.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeout.current) // cancel scheduled hiding of tooltip
      timeout.current = null
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => () => {
    // when component unmounts, clear scheduled hiding - nothing to hide by this point=)
    if (timeout.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeout.current)
      timeout.current = null
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <label className='checkbox-a'>
      <input
        {...input}
        checked={checked} 
        type='checkbox'
      />
      <div className='checkbox-a__box' id={name} />
      <div>
        <p
          className='checkbox--links'
          tabindex='0'
          aria-describedby='tooltip-cb'
          className='tooltip'
          onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
          onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
        >
          <u>{label}</u>
          {/* render tooltip conditionally */}
          {isShowing && <div
            role='tooltip'
            class='tooltip__content'
            id='tooltip-cb-02'
          >
            {hover}
          </div>}
        </p>
      </div>
    </label>
  )
}
```

Alternatively, this can be done with a class component - let me know if you want an example of that as well.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi...i tried but it doesn't work the way it is expected to ....thanks for the comments ...it lets understand the beginners like me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **open** prop of the Tooltip to set the timeout on **onMouseEnter** event and set this.state.tooltipIsOpen to false into your class state.

```
<Tooltip
  arrow
  title={<h6 className="my-auto">Manage Account</h6>}
  placement="bottom"
  style={{ color: "white", background: "transparent" }}
  open={this.state.tooltipIsOpen}
/>
```